# Connect iOS Device to Mac and Log App Errors

Tags: ios, macos, testing, appium

Goal:

1. Connect iOS device (physical device) to macbook
2. Use Appium / IntelliJ / or any other software to capture app errors from the device

I run automation tests using simulated devices, however, it's proving to not be as affective as manual testing for I'm getting different results. What I want is to simply connect my device to my macbook, run something to log app errors as I interact with my test device.

My current set up to run automated tests:

Appium

IntelliJ - Using simulated devices (No longer wanting to do)

Comment: What kind of "app errors" are you looking to log? If it's not a crash, the device doesn't really know what an "error" is and there will be nothing logged.

I've provided an answer below that based on my understanding of what you have access to is the extent of what you're going to be capable of.

Comment: @MikeCollins Hello, I need to be able to interact with an app developed at my work place, and I want to see activity of the app and any errors that may occur when interacting with say a Questionnaire, or a checkbox, things of that nature. I don't need to see device activity but that may be something I can consider later to have a better understanding of device limitation, but that's a discussion for another time.

Comment: Again, you need to better define what an "error" is. Is there debugging in your application you're seeking access to? No tool can know your app's functionality and report on it without being told expectations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @MikeCollins. I think I'll have to post pone this for another time. Thank you for your reply and insight to this.

Answer (score 0):

To view what's going on in the device, you'll need to use Xcode. The easiest way to obtain that is to use the **Mac App Store application**.

If you're able to build your app there is a lot more debugging you can do, but I'm assuming you're not able to do that based on what you've written and won't provide instruction on that.

1. Attach device
2. Launch **Xcode**
3. Click **Window** menu
4. Click **Devices and Simulators**
5. Unlock device
6. Click **Open Console** if you're looking to see live activity of the system (this is very noisy and unlikely to be of much use) or **View Device Logs** to see any crash reports.